# Adding custom frameworks in android

Tags: java, android, class, jar, android-framework

I'm making a root access app which generates touch event from the background. Generating touch events requires `INJECT_EVENTS` permission which is actually a Signature level permission. Since I cannot have the same signature as the ROM so I thought of two solutions as of now :

1. Create a .jar class out of a class which actually generates the touch event and call the method of this class from my app and pass coordinates as the arguments. And then push this jar file to `/system/framework/`
2. The second thing which I thought of was to inject the above created class inside the `framework.jar` only and then call the method of the class.

I wanted to ask which of the solution might work or if anyone has another idea in their mind, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It might work on `system/framework`, I'm uncertain. 
You can also try this, http://allmydroids.blogspot.de/2014/04/android-system-platform-signed.html

Comment: I'll try patching the framework. And I actually want to release the app to play store so the link is not useful in my case.

Comment: play store will never install application as `system` or `root`.

Comment: The app itself is for rooted users. I can do anything with root access.